# Duplicated function : subset a column number instead a column name

Tags: python, duplicates, subset

I have this :

```
data['Duplicated']=data.duplicated(subset='Name')
```

It's working, but I'd like to chang the column name 'Email' by his column number, like this :

```
data['Duplicated']=data.duplicated(subset=data.iloc[:,1])
```

But this last code is not working. Is it possible to do it with another method please?

Thanks a lot in advance, have a good day !

Comment: Have you tried printing  `data.iloc[:,2]` ? What does that return?

Comment: data1=pd.DataFrame(data = {'ID_Client': [12,13,11,14],
                     'Name': ['Bryan','John','Sonya','Mark'],
                     'Birth_date': ['10-06-2001','12-08-1991','14-06-1976','15-06-1962'],
                     'Email':['bryan@gmail.com','john@hotmail.com','',''],
                     'SMS':['','0718181818','0611111111','0688888888']})
data1.head()

Comment: data2=pd.DataFrame(data = {'ID_Client': [32,48,21,8],
                     'Name': ['Mark','Bryan','John','Emma'],
                     'Birth_date': ['15-06-1962','10-06-2001','12-08-1991','14-06-1976'],
                     'Email':['','not-bryan@gmail.com','john@hotmail.com','emma@gmail.com'],
                     'SMS':['0688888888','','0718181818','']})
    data2.head()

Comment: data3 = pd.concat([data1, data2], ignore_index=True)

Comment: data3['Duplicated']=data3.duplicated(subset=data3.iloc[:,1])

Comment: and the error I get is : KeyError: Index(['Bryan', 'Emma', 'John', 'Mark', 'Sonya'], dtype='object')